# What's the most concise way to get an Oracle resultset into a printable array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oracle

Is this the most concise way of getting results from Oracle using Ruby?

```
require 'oci8'
results_array = Array.new
oci.exec('select column_a from table_a') do |row|
  results_array.push(row)
end
results_array.each do |result|
  puts result
end
```

I was hoping to see something more concise such as:

```
require 'oci8'
results_array = oci.exec('select column_a from table_a')
puts results_array
```

But I get an Oracle Cursor error when I try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to `puts` the rows:

```
oci.exec('select column_a from table_a') { |row| puts row}
```

If you want to build an array to keep that for later:

```
results_array = []
oci.exec('select column_a from table_a') { |row| results_array << row }
puts results_array.join("\n")
```

Hope this helps :)